# How to filter number and date in GridView using RowFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a web application in C#. I want to filter a GridView with selecting a column from a listBox and then instantly filter the table accordingly to the text the user typed into a textBox using RowFilter.

I already managed nearly the whole part, but I've stuck trying to solve the comparison for numbers and dates.

The comparison for text works well:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text + " LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

For numbers I tried something like this (didn't work):

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text + " = '#{0}#'", textBox1.Text);
```

I guess comparison for numbers and dates will be pretty much the same as for text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will be helpful to you...

```
        string colname = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
        string value = textBox1.Text;
        if (colname != null && dt.Columns[colname] != null)
        {
            if ("Byte,Decimal,Double,Int16,Int32,Int64,SByte,Single,UInt16,UInt32,UInt64,".Contains(dt.Columns[colname].DataType.Name + ","))
            {
                dv.RowFilter = colname + "=" + value;
            }
            else if (dt.Columns[colname].DataType == typeof(string))
            {
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format(colname + " LIKE '%{0}%'", value);
            }
            else if (dt.Columns[colname].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                dv.RowFilter = colname + " = #" + value + "#";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [DataView RowFilter Syntax](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

These are syntax rules for RowFilter on DataGridView with strings, numbers and dates.

**Strings**

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'John'"        // string value
dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'John ''A'''"  // string with single quotes "John 'A'"
dataView.RowFilter = String.Format("Name = '{0}'", "John 'A'".Replace("'", "''"));
```

**Numbers**

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Year = 2008"          // integer value
dataView.RowFilter = "Price = 1199.9"       // float value
dataView.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,
                     "Price = {0}", 1199.9f);
```

**Dates**

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #12/31/2008#"          // date value (time is 00:00:00)
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #2008-12-31#"          // also this format is supported
dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #12/31/2008 16:44:58#" // date and time value
dataView.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                     "Date = #{0}#", new DateTime(2008, 12, 31, 16, 44, 58));
```

Comment: @Dentox9 Which problems?

Comment: There occurred problems while converting numbers or dates and compare them with each other. You're code is using dataView, but I'm using GridView, so probably there's a difference between the comparison functions. However, the solution from Sangram solved it.