# My task is to implement filter functionality in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

In my sqlserver database there is a coloumn in my table called jobid which is decimal(this datatype can't be changed.), and the input that I get from my textbox is string that is where the problem comes.

I wrote statement like this

```
dv.Rowfilter="JOBID LIKE '%"+textbox.text+"%'"
```

Where dv is a dataview and the table exists. When I try to compile this visual studio says `System.INT32` cannot be compared with `System.String`. Then I tried to change the textbox input to decimal by using `convert.ToDecimal()`. But now I can't use the like for comparing two decimals. Can someone help me with this.
Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: remove single quote near %

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158264/how-to-filter-number-and-date-in-gridview-using-rowfilter